# How can I format my USB sticks using Linux so that they work on Android?

Tags: linux, android, raspberry-pi

How can I format my USB sticks using Linux so that they work on Android?

So I have been stuck on this now for a few hours. Strange issues.

I am trying to format two usb sticks (one has a removable SD card, the other one is a SanDisk Cruzer) as vfat, which as far as I know is the preferred filesystem for Android USB OTG usb sticks.

However, now Android cannot see them or mount them anymore which means they won't show up in storage.

I think I was able to successfully format them as vfat on the RPi just now but they still won't show up on the phone.

I could reformat them directly on the Android phone but they won't even show up so I cannot reformat either.

Any advice?

Computer: RPi3B
Mobile phone: Samsung Galaxy S5

Vesa

Comment: Vfat is not a disk format.

Comment: Do the sticks have a partition table?

Comment: FAT32 should work and is pretty universal for compatibility with other devices.

Comment: You probably mean exfat. Android only recognizes FAT32.

Comment: @Ignacio I have tried adding a partition table but the phone just won't recognize the usb sticks at all. I have tried on another phone too but it also did not recognize them.

Comment: @fixer1234 Well maybe. As far as I remember they were formatted as FAT32 once and the phone could recognize them but now when I try doing that nothing happens. They won't show up at all on the phone.

Comment: What commands are you using to format them?

Comment: Verify that your USB host (cable etc.) still works with something else (e.g. keyboard, mouse). It might be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

`mkdosfs` from the package `dosfstools` will help you here. To use:

```
mkdosfs -F 32 [your-usb-stick]
```

Note that `mkfs.fat` only seems to format a disk as FAT16. Why? No clue.

Comment: I think it depends on the size of the volume.

Comment: Possible; I tested mkfs.fat on a 400MB partition of a random USB stick.

Comment: I had no issue making a Fat32 partition on a 16GB stick

Comment: With mkfs.fat or mkdosfs?

Comment: msdosfs -F 32 /dev/sdd1

Comment: Try it with mkfs.fat.

Comment: This isn't really a discussion forum... You gave your answer and I made a relevant comment. How is your request relevant to the answer?

Comment: Will test when I have a chance as soon as possible

Comment: In that case nevermind.